# JOOQ Maven plugin - encoding of generated source files

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, jooq

How can I set the encoding of the files generated by the JOOQ Maven plugin?
(The problem is that in our database the comments contain non-ANSI characters and these are included in the generated files as javadoc comments.)

I cannot find a configuration option for it, and the encoding seems to be ISO-8859-1, the default JVM encoding...

Comment: As a quick solution I use the antrun plugin to convert the generated sources (using the <copy> task).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the JVM encoding by passing the `-Dfile.encoding=...` JVM argument when running the code generator. jOOQ itself supports specifying the encoding of generated files since jOOQ 3.8 ([issue #4517](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4517)):

```xml
<configuration>
    ...
    <generator>
        ...
        <target>
            ...
            <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```